# django signals: receiver and proxy model?

Tags: django, django-signals

I set a receiver on a `post_save` signal and I was hoping catching the signals for all the proxy of my Model by setting the sender to the main Model but it does not seem to work:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    ....

class MyObjectProxy(MyObject):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

# The receiver
# How to avoid writing another one for sender=MyObjectProxy ?
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyObject)
...
```

My receiver is not triggered when that happens:

```
obj = MyObjectProxy()
obj.save()
```

Is that normal?
I have to set a receiver for each proxy?
Can I set `sender` to a list of models?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `MyObjectProxy`?

Comment: A Proxy Model, I'm updating my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Umm. Signals fire when you save an instance of the model. Why are you calling save() on the model class?

Comment: yes, I made a mistake in my example. I changed it.

Comment: @Michael Did you solve this issue at that time? I got the same issue here.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, I think that a list of models is the only working way. There is an [open discussion](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9318) about that specific issue.

Comment: so I can have  ``sender=[]`` ? Thanks

Comment: Actually no, you cannot. The `receiver` decorator accepts only a signal (or a list of signals) and a single sender as kwarg.